# how to open web page and click on element?

Tags: java, android

I'm building an app on Android, and I want it when I press any button in the application

It will open a web page and enter Text TextBox and click the button
On this web page automatically (all this should be run behind the scenes - that the user will not see)

Is there any possibility to develop this?

Comment: I hope this is not, and never will be possible... Very shady practice.

Comment: put a editext on top of view and set alpha 0 or full transparent then set focusable to true

Answer (score 0):

thank's for help, I try to input text 'java help' in google search and then click button search, and it's not work.

I download "inspect html" in the android device and get from there the name class of the elements of the input text and button of google search page.

this is the code:

```
        public void onClick(View view) {

            WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.il/?hl=iw");
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByClassName('gLFyf').value = 'java help';})()");
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { var z = document.getElementsByClassName('Tg7LZd').click(); })()");
       }
```

thank's shani