# android - open web page and click on element not work

Tags: javascript, java, android

[the first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967755/how-to-open-web-page-and-click-on-element/51121994#51121994)

I try to input text 'java help' in google search and then click button search, and it's not work.
I download "inspect html" in the android device and get from there the name class of the elements of the input text and button of google search page.
this is the code:
        public void onClick(View view) {

```
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.il/?hl=iw");
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByClassName('gLFyf').value = 'java help';})()");
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { var z = document.getElementsByClassName('Tg7LZd').click(); })()");
   }
```

thank's shani

Comment: Does the same javascript call work in your webbrowser on your pc? Copy and paste it, open developer tools and execute it.

Comment: Also slightly on topic, those classnames are generated dynamically by Google. They might change once you refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer :  [send a Web intent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28869131/9981067)

```
private final static String BASE_URL = "https://www.google.com/search";
private final static String QUERY = "q";

Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY, "your input text that you want to search")
    .build();

URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
```

you could use the code above to make your Url and then use below code to open the browser :

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(
  Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)
);

activity.startActivity(browserIntent);
activity.finish();
```